# Accesing script located on a separate server via curl and manipulating sessions/cookies and database as well?

Tags: php, session, cookies, libcurl

I'm stuck in a very complicated situation (its probably just me with my lack of experience).

- I'm working on two different servers **server A** and **server B**
- from a script on **server A** i need to access a script located on **server B**
- and **insert the session and query string** data from **server A**'s script into the **Server B**'s Database through the script located on **server B**.

Simple **include()** doesn't work for external servers so i'm using **curl** but i'm very confused

How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the session and query string from server A to server B (it is better to do through https connection). Just form the Session and query string as params, do urlencode and send them to server B through GET or POST. Server B can respond with some data - put this data to array and do serialization or json_encode. When you will receive it on server A do unserialize or json_decode and you will get your data from server B.

Comment: u mean through the GET method?

Comment: and what about the variable values that i want to retrieve from that script?